# How to replace + with - in search URL

Tags: html, url, urlencode

I want to create a search which searches some other website from my website,
The problem is that other website is uses - instead of + for example: `https://somewebsite.com/?search=example-search-query` but when I use this code:

```
<form class="example" method="get" action="https://europixhd.io/svop2/zznewsrv4" style="margin:auto;max-width:300px">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Movie Name Here..." name="search">
  <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></button>
</form>
```

It of course adds a + instead of a -
any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a function that is binded to the submit action

```
<html>
<form class="example" method="get" action="" id="formID" style="margin:auto;max-width:300px">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Movie Name Here..." name="search" id="search">
  <button type="submit" ><i class="fa fa-play"></i></button>
</form>
</html>
<script>
var form = document.querySelector('#formID');
form.addEventListener('submit', searchUpdater);

function searchUpdater() {
  var text = document.getElementById("search").value.replace(" ", "-"); 
  document.getElementById("search").value = text;
  return true;
}
</script>
```